# stuck in Webdriver python

Tags: python, webdriver

Please help me out. I have tried each possibility and still no
solution.

1. Where the hell is webElement in python. I checked the API's and
   found its in selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement

However to use this I need to create a object. webelement requires 2
arguments. What are those. any idea??

1. There is no send_keys for webdriver object. PLEASE help me in this.
2. Whenever I do driver.find_elements_by_class_name() or any other
   find operation, the return should be a webelement. I cannot do any
   operations on the return value. When I try to do something always get
   an exception.
3. I tried doing webdriver.Firefox.create_webelement as well. It also
   requires some argument. Any idea what argument its is?

My main issue is send_keys just doesn't work. I have reverified that I
have installed selenium in python correctly. Done everything.

Please help guys. Any suggestion would be great. If anyone shares a
tutorial then it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find the webelement you want to interact with:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
my_element = driver.find_element_by_id('someid')
my_element.send_keys('this is a test')
my_button = driver.find_element_by_name('button')
my_button.click()
```